# Byte order: converting java bytes to c#

Tags: c#, .net, porting

While converting a Java application to C# I came through a strange and very annoying piece of code, which is crucial and works in the original version.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[length];
byte[] buf2 = bout.toByteArray();
System.arraycopy(buf2, 0, buf, 0, buf2.length);;
for (int i = (int) offset; i < (int) length; ++i) {
  buf[i] = (byte) 255;
}
```

The part which is causing a casting error is the set into `buf[i]` of the byte 255: while in Java it works fine, since `java.lang.Byte` spans from 0 to 255, .NET `System.Byte` spans from 0 to 254.
Because of this limitation, the output in the C# version of the application is that instead of 255, as expected, the buffer contains a set of 254.

Could anyone give me a viable alternative?

Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Uhm, what makes you think a .NET byte doesn't go to 255?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.80).aspx -- the range is 255. Is there something else going on in the code?

Comment: Java bytes are signed, so (byte) 255 is (byte) -1. Not sure if that makes any difference to whatever this does.

Comment: sorry all guys: it seems I've just written foobar... :P
thank you all for the fast answers :)

Comment: @Pete: In C#, `((byte)-1)` is not allowed because `-1` cannot be represented by a `byte`. You have to use `unchecked((byte)(-1))` to suppress the compiler's check for this.

Comment: @Antonello: then select an answer it or close the question, please.

Comment: @Antonello: Before you close the question, do you want to post more of your code so that we can see what it was trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misdiagnosed your problem: .NET bytes are 8-bit like everyone else's.  A better approach is to try to understand what the Java code is trying to do, then figure out what the cleanest equivalent is in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be because you're casting the 255 integer literal to a byte, rather than assigning a byte value. I recommend you try using using [`Byte.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.maxvalue.aspx) instead. Byte.MaxValue has a value of 255.

For example:

```
buf[i] = byte.MaxValue;
```

**Edit:** I was wrong; `(byte)255` definitely evaluates to 255; I've just confirmed in VS. There must be something you're doing to cause the change elsewhere in your code.

Comment: "The value of this constant is 255 (hexadecimal 0xFF)."

Comment: I'm aware of that. But he's trying to cast 255, which is an integer literal, to a byte. I think *that* may be causing the problem he keeps seeing. Instead of using the cast, I recommend using Byte.MaxValue, which has the value of 255. I shall edit and clarify.

Comment: No, you can cast 255 to byte just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I fired up VS and tried it; (byte)255 definitely evaluates to 255. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @Randolpho: Expanding on Steven's comment, you can cast any integer literal without a suffix to a variable capable of representing it *without a cast*. -1 can be assigned to sbyte, short, int, long. 0xFFFFFFFF can be assigned to uint, long, ulong. 255 can be assigned to any integer type except sbyte.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, stupid C# compiler is too smart for me. I thought that maybe the cast was causing the problem; clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[`byte.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.maxvalue.aspx) equals 255.

> The value of this constant is 255 (hexadecimal 0xFF).

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure about this C# "limitation", according to MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx

The C# byte is an unsigned 8 bit integer with values that can range between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx)

byte:

The byte keyword denotes an integral type that stores values as indicated in the following table.

- .NET Framework type: System Byte
- Range:               byte    0 to 255
- Size : Unsigned 8-bit integer